# Using std::experimental::optional giving compilation errors

Tags: c++, c++11, boost-optional

I am using the optional feature for the 1st time, any idea what is wrong in this code I wish to retrieve the value from the tuple which is stored in `retCode`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <experimental/optional>
std::experimental::optional<std::tuple<uint16_t, uint32_t, uint32_t>> addEntity();

  std::experimental::optional<std::tuple<uint16_t, uint32_t, uint32_t>> addEntity() {
    uint32_t ipR = 1111;
    uint32_t ipU = 2222;
    uint16_t entityId = 0;
    return std::make_tuple(entityId, ipR, ipU);
  }


int main()
{
  auto retCode =  addEntity();
  std::cout<<std::get<0>(retCode)<<std::endl;
  return 0;

}
```

**Compilation Errors**

```
g++ experiment.cpp
In file included from /usr/include/c++/7/bits/move.h:54:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/7/bits/nested_exception.h:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/7/exception:143,
                 from /usr/include/c++/7/ios:39,
                 from /usr/include/c++/7/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/7/iostream:39,
                 from experiment.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/7/type_traits: In instantiation of ‘struct std::is_trivially_destructible<std::tuple<short unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned int> >’:
/usr/include/c++/7/experimental/optional:203:5:   required from ‘class std::experimental::fundamentals_v1::optional<std::tuple<short unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned int> >’
```

Comment: `#include <tuple>` is missing, and if you can use C++17, you will have `std::optional` directly.

Comment: Looks like the destructor of `std::tuple` is only trivially destructible from C++17 https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple

Comment: Which GCC version are you using? It has to support C++17 for `std::tuple`. Did you set the compiler flag `-std=c++17`?

Comment: @BJovke `std::tuple` is C++11 source: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple

Comment: yes I am using `-std=c++17`

Comment: So what happens *after* you add the missing header?

Comment: @Jarod42 after including `tuple` I am getting this error on retrieving value `error: no matching function for call to ‘get<0>(std::experimental::fundamentals_v1::optional<std::tuple<short unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned int> >&)’
   std::cout<<std::get<0>(retCode)<<std::endl;
                                 ^
`

Comment: @StoryTeller `error: no matching function for call to ‘get<0>(std::experimental::fundamentals_v1::optional<std::tuple<short unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned int> >&)’ std::cout<<std::get<0>(retCode)<<std::endl;`

Comment: Yes, because an optional is not a tuple. You can get via `value()` a tuple out of it though.

Comment: You need to check the std::optional as bool first. It has an overload for bool comparison. **Only if it's true** you're allowed to read the value from it, otherwise it's undefined behavior and your program will crash. That's the whole point of std::optional, to tell you if the function produced a result or not.

Comment: @StoryTeller looks like we are close how will that look like `std::cout<<std::get<0>(retCode.value())<<std::endl;`

Comment: @RichardCritten Yes, it's a C++11 object, but you haven't read my comment carefully. `std::tuple` is trivially destructible only since C++17 and that is required for `std::optional`.

Comment: It worked thank you guys for all your help :)

Comment: @VinayShukla **You have to check if there's a value present in `std::optional`**: `if (retCode) std::cout << std::get<0>(retCode.value());`. You must not read the value before the check is done and it's `true`.

Comment: @BJovke - It's redundant if one uses `value` like the OP. That one checks and throws.

Comment: @StoryTeller I don't think so. The idea behind `std::optional` is to have a normal flow branch depending on if value is present or not. You are explicitly saying that you are **expecting** that both outcomes can happen. The idea behind exceptions is that **you should never use them as a flow control**, only for rare **unexpected** situations during program execution. The fact that this can work with having the exception in mind is just a convenience. Still, based on the example, the program is ill formed because there's no `try..catch` block and it aborts.

Comment: @StoryTeller Why would you bother with `std::optional` anyway if you are catching the exception on `std::optional` not having a value stored? Why not just throw from inside the called function, without using `std::optional` at all? That's far more simpler.

Comment: All of the above comments are pure speculation. The shown "compilation errors" in the question itself is completely missing the real compilation error -- it only shows the initial context of the actual compilation error (which probably appears on the very next line of the output), and for some bizarre reason the question seems to omit -- so the actual compilation error could be anything.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Yes, but only if it's a plain template error. In this case the library designers have put checks for the stored type so the first line tells you right away what's the problem: `std::is_trivially_destructible` for `std::tuple` is not true.

Comment: @BJovke - The idea behind optional is to support the model that fits the client. There is no problem with checking and using `*`. There is no problem with assuming it's there via `value` and propogating an exception. However , *there is* a problem with both checking explicitly *and* calling `value`. It shows a fundamental lack of understanding about the API.

Comment: @StoryTeller _It shows a fundamental lack of understanding about the API_ Care to provide an explanation or reference to how you came to this conclusion? It's very simple: if you want to use the exception then the function can return just `std::tuple` and throw in case of no value. `std::optional` is not needed at all in that case.

Comment: @BJovke - *"It's very simple: if you want to use the exception then the function can return just std::tuple and throw in case of no value"* Which is spelled as a simple call to `value`. No need to add superfluous checks.

Comment: @StoryTeller But you don't need `std::optional` at all in that case. So what's the point of **unnecessarily** adding `std::optional` and relying on exception? What do you think method `has_value()` and `bool` overload (which do the same thing) of `std::optional` are used for then?

Comment: @BJovke - You assume you have control over all functions you call. That doesn't hold in general. Besides, `optional` is a vocabulary type for a reason. Instead of writing a bunch of function that do checked and unchecked access, it suffices to return an optional, and let clients handle it how they see fit. That's how you use vocabulary.

Answer (score 0):

There's no implicit conversion from `optional<T>` to `T`, you need to extract the value.

```
int main()
{
  auto retCode =  addEntity();
  std::cout<<std::get<0>(retCode.value())<<std::endl; // can throw std::bad_optional_access
  return 0;
}
```

Unless you have other places which **require** `addEntity` to return an optional tuple, not just places where you call `addEntity` *to initialise* an optional tuple, it should just **return a tuple**.